# Activity selection algorithm with 2 types of activities

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve this problem using dynamic programming and I can't figure how to define the sub-problems and the relation between them.

So it's basically the same as the regular activity selection problem only that you have 2 type of activities (let's call them yellow and gray) so each activity has a starting time finish time and a color.
yellow activities have an higher priority than gray ones so if a yellow activity overlaps with 2 gray activities the yellow one will get into the solution and the gray activities won't.

thanks.

Comment: Split them into 2 collections, try select 2 from Grays and 1 from Yellows like you do with regular selection problem, compare -> get new time stamp -> remove invalid activities (from both collection)

Comment: Be precise: What if a yellow activity overlaps 3 grey activities?  What if a single yellow activity overlaps 1000 non-overlapping grey activities -- do we still pick the 1 yellow, instead of the 1000 grey?

Comment: one yellow activity will be chosen over any amount of non-overlapping grey activities. @j_random_hacker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split them into 2 collections, try select 2 from Grays and 1 from Yellows like you do with regular selection problem, compare -> get new time stamp -> remove invalid activities (from both collection)

```
A = { }, Selection
loop {
   G1 = Select(1 from Gray)  
   Y1 = Select(1 from Yellow)  
   if (Y1.finish < G1.finish) { 
      Selection = Y1;
   }
   else {
      G2 = Select(2 from Gray)
      if (Y1.finish < G2.finish)
          Selection = Y1;
      else
          Selection = {G1, G2}
   }

   A = A U Selection;
   LowerBound = Selection.Last.Finish;
   RemoveFrom(Yellow : have starting time < LowerBound)
   RemoveFrom(Gray   : have starting time < LowerBound)       
}
```

Note:

- Gray and Yellow should be sorted like in the original problem
- Select is the normal select operation you would do in the original
  problem
  -> So `Select(2...)` doesnt mean select the first 2 in the
  collection, but the first 2 do-able activities
- For easy implementation, consider using 2 queues, and some other technique to get the LowerBound, should be O(n) time and space (minus the sorting) if implemented correctly